# USB Ethernet adapter keeps failing every few minutes on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-adapter

The OS is Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a model "DELL Inspiron 13 5379 2-in-1" laptop.

Everything else is OK, except for a disconnecting issue on the network. The hardware does not have an Ethernet port, so I am using a TP-Link UE300 adapter. However, the connection fails once every few minutes. And please see the below partial error message collected at the time of failure in file `/var/log/syslog`.

Unfortunately, we cannot include the log file of a complete failure cycle due to the limitation of word counts. If necessary, please point a place for us to upload the file.

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions, and please let us know of any questions.

```
... repeating events ...

Mar 20 20:07:39 hostname systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname kernel: [ 8119.057000] usb 1-1.4.2: USB disconnect, device number 118
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname kernel: [ 8119.057016] usb 1-1.4.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 119
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname kernel: [ 8119.057329] r8152 1-1.4.2.3:1.0 enxd0.........3: Stop submitting intr, status -108
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname avahi-daemon[743]: Interface enxd0.........3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname avahi-daemon[743]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enxd0.........3.IPv4 with address 192.168.xxx.xxx.
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname avahi-daemon[743]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.xxx.xxx on enxd0.........3.
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1679364476.1325] device (enxd0.........3): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1679364476.1518] dhcp4 (enxd0.........3): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1679364476.1519] dhcp4 (enxd0.........3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1679364476.1520] dhcp4 (enxd0.........3): state changed no lease
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname NetworkManager[750]: <info>  [1679364476.1549] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname dbus-daemon[749]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=750 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: Object St.BoxLayout (0x55ab8a72dae0), has been already disposed — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ab866db4b0 ==
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #0   55ab86fc5fa8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:766 (3b5d2e715420 @ 22)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #1   55ab86fc5ef8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:686 (3b5d2e7151a0 @ 27)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #2   55ab86fc5e40 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:301 (5778257b790 @ 147)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #3   55ab86fc5da0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:291 (5778257b740 @ 117)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #4   55ab86fc5d18 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1853 (5778257e380 @ 20)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #5   7ffe8f6f21a0 b   self-hosted:202 (57782507240 @ 272)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #6   55ab86fc5c88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1852 (5778257e330 @ 101)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #7   55ab86fc5bf8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1840 (5778257e2e0 @ 18)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ab866db4b0 ==
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #0   55ab86fc5ef8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:699 (3b5d2e7151a0 @ 283)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #1   55ab86fc5e40 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:301 (5778257b790 @ 147)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #2   55ab86fc5da0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:291 (5778257b740 @ 117)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #3   55ab86fc5d18 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1853 (5778257e380 @ 20)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #4   7ffe8f6f21a0 b   self-hosted:202 (57782507240 @ 272)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #5   55ab86fc5c88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1852 (5778257e330 @ 101)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #6   55ab86fc5bf8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1840 (5778257e2e0 @ 18)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ab866db4b0 ==
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #0   55ab86fc5ef8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:699 (3b5d2e7151a0 @ 283)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #1   55ab86fc5e40 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:301 (5778257b790 @ 147)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #2   55ab86fc5da0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:291 (5778257b740 @ 117)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #3   55ab86fc5d18 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1853 (5778257e380 @ 20)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #4   7ffe8f6f21a0 b   self-hosted:202 (57782507240 @ 272)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #5   55ab86fc5c88 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1852 (5778257e330 @ 101)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: Object St.BoxLayout (0x55ab8a72dae0), has been already disposed — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname dbus-daemon[749]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #6   55ab86fc5bf8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1840 (5778257e2e0 @ 18)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ab866db4b0 ==
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #0   55ab86fc5fa8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:766 (3b5d2e715420 @ 22)
Mar 20 20:07:56 hostname gnome-shell[1669]: #1   55ab86fc5ef8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/popupMenu.js:686 (3b5d2e7151a0 @ 27)

... still more lines below ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the adapter is marked for DHCP to get its IP address, and it's failing because no DHCP server responded. You can use "settings" to set a static IP to stop the noise.